# Message Contracts in WCF REST Service

Tags: c#, json, xml, wcf, wcf-rest

Can we use Message Contracts with WCF Rest Service?

Message Contract will add the header in XML if we define Message header attribute in Message Contract class.

But WCF rest deals with JSOn so we won't have the header for JSON.

So how we can use Message Contracts with WCF Rest Service?

Comment: Well, you can use a JSON body inside a SOAP envelope.

Comment: You can configure a restful wcf endpoint to return data in a number of formats. Just because the endpoint is "restful" does not mean it can't be configured to return traditional soap alongside json.

Comment: We can use Message Contracts in WCF Rest, but that returns data as XML?